# Matrix Algebraic Manipulation Involving Inverse and Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a paper where authors denote $\bar{G_k} = I - G_k(G_k^TG_k)^{-1}G_k^T$. Now, I am trying to verify it and reduce the second term to see what it is. I am doing the following, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

$$= G_k(G_k^TG_k)^{-1}G_k^T$$

Simplifying the inverse term, using $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, we have,

$$= G_kG_k^{-1}(G_k^T)^{-1}G_k^T$$

Now, multiplying the first two terms (is it allowed (associativity)?), using $AA^{-1} = I$ we get,

$$= I(G_k^T)^{-1}G_k^T$$

Similarly, the last two terms,

$$= II$$

$$= I$$

Please let me know where I am doing it wrong. I am not mathematically trained, so would appreciate any help.

Comment: In you paper, is $G_k$ a square matrix? because what you wrote is true iff $G_k$ is square. While $G_k^T G_k$ may have an inverse (e.g. if $G_k$ has size $m \times n$ with $m\geqslant n$ and is of full rank), if $n \neq m$, $G_k$ does not have an inverse

Comment: I completely missed that. Indeed, $G_k$ is not a square matrix. Thanks a lot! @julio_es_sui_glace

Comment: No problem, I had this issue recently so I can relate!

Answer (score 0):

Let $G^{\bf+}$ denote the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) of $G\,$
which (unlike the ordinary matrix inverse) exists for rectangular matrices.

The [Hat Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)#Definition_and_interpretations) is defined as
$$H \;=\; G(G^TG)^{-1}G^T \;=\; GG^{\bf+}$$

Note that $H=H^T$ and projects into the column-space of $G:\;\; HG = G$

What the authors call $\hat G$ is the complementary projector $(I-H)$

which projects into the nullspace of $G:\;\; \hat GG = 0$